# JPA delete fails (integrity constraint violation: foreign key no action) - data model too convoluted?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm experiencing a problem I cannot get my head around. I really hope someone out there can help.

#### Entity model

This might get a little meta as my data model represents programming objects. I've got three entities: Program, Clazz and Method. Classes can have multiple methods and occasionally inherited some other methods (from other classes).

```
@Entity
public class Program {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="program", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("name ASC")
    private Set<Clazz> clazzes = new TreeSet<Clazz>();
}

@Entity
public class Clazz {

    @ManyToOne
    private Program program;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="clazz", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("name ASC")
    private Set<Method> methods = new TreeSet<Method>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="inheritedBy")
    @OrderBy("name ASC")
    private Set<Method> inheritedMethods = new TreeSet<Method>();

    @PreRemove
    private void tearDown() {
        inheritedMethods.clear();
    }

}

@Entity @Table(name="sf_method")
public class Method {

    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
    private Clazz clazz;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "sf_method_inherited_by_class", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "sf_method_inherited_by_class") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "sf_class_inherits_method") }
    )
    private Set<Clazz> inheritedBy = new HashSet<Clazz>();

    @PreRemove
    public void tearDown() {
        inheritedBy.clear();
    }

}
```

#### My problem: what I do

What I need to do is to delete a program, including all its classes and methods. I use Spring-JPA repositories, so my code is:

```
@Autowired ProgramRepository programs;

@Transactional(readOnly=false)
public void forceDelete(Program p) {
    Set<Clazz> myClasses = p.getClazzes();
    for (Clazz c : myClasses) {
        logger.info("Clazz " + c.getName());
        for (Method m : c.getMethods()) {
            m.setClazz(null);
            methods.save(m);
        }
    }
    programs.delete(p);
}
```

#### What happens

The delete code works only in some circumstances. Sometimes I get the following error.

> SqlExceptionHelper - integrity constraint violation: foreign key no
>   action; FKIBMDD2FV8TNJAF4VJTOEICS73 table: SF_METHOD AbstractBatchImpl
>   - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements

Any idea? I spent so many hours on this and I failed every single resolution attempt. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You would need to show us the code that deletes something. Also it seems strange that the class "Method" has a reference to a "Class" while in the "Class" there is a list of "Method", you are not referencing the same "Class" in the list that you also assign to the "method", cause that would be an endless loop.

Comment: I've updated the question to include it. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here you are trying to delete the parent without deleting the child which have foreign key referencing to the parent.

Here, before you delete *p* you have to delete children for p.
You can get that by :
p.getClazzes();

Again before deleting Clazz, you have to delete children for it(in this case, Method) as above...

Comment: Nop, he is doing it right because he define cascade ALL (which includes cascade on Remove) behavior for the parent-children relationships.

Comment: Probably the problém is that je uses Cascade.ALL too much. It may cause cyclic behavior with bidirectional references. @Lorenzo, are you aute that Cascade.ALL should be on `Method.inheritedBy`? This would also mean that when a method is deleted with class, ako classes that inherit it would be deleted, and for them ako inherited methods would be deleted again, which cause this problém with foreign key.

Comment: On next thought, Cascade.ALL or Cascade.REMOVE should be used logically only where an entity 'owns' other entities, therefore you should remove it also from `Clazz.inheritedMethods`, as these methods are owned by other Clazz. Do not forget to call `Method.inheritedBy.remove(deletedClazz)` to remove references to ako clazzes deletwd with program

Comment: Thanks guys for trying to help out. As suggested by @OndrejM I removed all the unnecessary cascades. I also included _PreRemove_ methods to make sure collections are emptied before deletion. Still isn't working! This thing is driving me mad...

Comment: As a last resort,try turning on SQL logging in hibernate to see which statement causes the error, as the error seems to be coming from the DB. Hopefully that helps you find out why such a statement is triggered from hibernate

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Any one has any solution for this?